# Gear watchface styling outside of Tizen IDE easily possible?

Tags: tizen-wearable-sdk, samsung-galaxy-gear

I wanted to develop my own watchface for my Gear S2. I found some good documentation on downloading and using the Tizen IDE. All is well, but I'm finding the tweak css/html5-run/upload-switch faces-view-wash-rinse-repeat to be very tedious and time-consuming.

I know I can point my browser (Chrome) to my development workspace and load the index.html up and I surmise that I could tweak what I have, which came from the template to work in the browser if I made the sizes in the css static vs dynamic (absolute vs percentages). But is there a better way? Scouring the Internets Googles have yielded nothing too helpful yet.

moderators: this might be OT for this particular SO. If that's the case, I apologize. A nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated, if so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I was able to make a little progress on this myself. I am using Chrome in developer mode, which almost works perfectly when using the developer device emulator. To toggle the device emulator, open developer mode (windows: ctrl+shift+I, OS X: cmd+option+i) and when the tool window opens up, look for the little device button next to the element button in the upper left corner of the developer tools window. When the device emulator open, switch the resolution to 320x320 (top of the window next to "screen").

Now, open your index.html file for your project in Chrome, and you can at least muck around with your css styling.

Now to get around the whole issue of reloading your clock with the default clock in the Java emulator for Tizen, I was able to get my changes to automatically assert when running the new code. The way I did it, though I'm not sure if all of these steps were necessary was:

In the emulated watch:
1. set the screen timeout to 15 mins.
2. set the watch face to your development watch face

In the IDE:
1. when ready, use the button for smart launch (it's the blue button just to the left of the bug button in the tizen web IDE). This is in the Tizen SDK version 2.3.1 build 20150721-1440.

At the time of running your code -- making sure both your emulated watch is running too:
1. In the IDE, click the smart launch button
2. Click over to your emulated watch and make sure it's in focus.

It *should* update the watch face with your latest changes in realtime. This worked for me, so YMMV, but at least I didn't have to reload the watch face after asserting the latest version.